# Rank over lateral flatten

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dense-rank

I'm curious on how to do a rank over group of values on lateral flatten.

So let's say I have a column that looks like:

```
id     tree
1     AB -> BC -> CD
2     A -> Z
3     B
```

I would like to get a result looking like this:

```
id     tree                flattened        ranker
1     AB -> BC -> CD          AB             1
1     AB -> BC -> CD          BC             2
1     AB -> BC -> CD          CD             3
2     A -> Z                   A             1
2     A -> Z                   Z             2
3     B                        B             1
```

I have implemented the lateral flatten but I don't know how to rank it.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a lateral flatten, one of the returned columns is the `INDEX`. That is the equivalent of the rank that you are looking for, except the values start at 0.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested,

the code would look like:

```
select table.*, c.value as flattened, rank() over (partition by id order by c.index) as ranker from table, lateral flatten(input => split(tree, ' -> ')) c;
```